# Inheritance program errors in methods

Tags: java

I'm having trouble implementing my sub class Customer I am getting the error 58  expected: "number="";" I am trying to get the customer class to inherit the methods in my Person class.

my program so far:

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Person
   {
   private String name;
   private String address;
   private String number;

   public Person() //No Argument constructor//
   {
    name= "";
    address= "";
    number= "" ;
   }

   public Person(String num, String nam, String add) //Explicit value constructor//
    {
   number= num;
   name= nam;
   address= add;
   }
   public String getName() //Accessor method//
    {
    return name;
    }

   public void setName(String name )//Mutator method//
   {

   this.name= name;
   }

   public String getAddress()
   {
   return address;
   }
    public void setAddress(String address)
    {
    this.address= address;
     }
    public String getTelephoneNumber()
    {
    return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number)
    {
    this.number= number;
    }

    public String toString ()
    {
    return name + "\n" + address + "\n" + number;
    }}

    public class Customer extends Person 
    {

    number="";

    public Customer(String num, String nam, String add) 
     {
     super (number);

     }

     public void addChoice(String number, boolean correct)
     {
      choice.add(choice);
      if (correct)
     {
      setAnswer(choiceString);
      }
       }
      public void display()
       {
      super.display();
       }
       }
```

Comment: basically the person class is the super class and the customer is the sub class and the questions contains other details on the methods and acessors used.

Comment: Ok I was just trying to say that I was having compiler errors and wanted to know why my Sub class was giving them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it is is pretty simple. You accidentally put an closing brace `}` instead of an opening brace `{` after the declaration of `getName`. Really easy to fix.

Comment: Ok lol ok now I feel dumb :$ but is my program decent either way

Comment: @user3019552 It's good, but the return type of `getAddress` should be `String`, not `Sting`.

Comment: I fixed that as well currently trying to implement a sub class will update soon for further correction

Comment: I have implemented a sub class is it right or wrong? I am also getting errors

Comment: Getting errors usually is a pretty good indicator that something is wrong.

Comment: Yeah I know but I want to inherit the methods and I want to know how i should fix my program in order to do so basically my sub class Customer.